# PHP function to convert a Portuguese word from plural to singular

Tags: php, strings, regex, i18n

I know, this sounds really difficult, but it is really easy.

I needed to convert a **single** Portuguese word in the plural into singular. I know there's a right name for that, but it is escaping me.

The rules are simple, and will compile them from http://www.easyportuguese.com/portuguese-lessons/plural/ (but applying in reverse):

- If the word ends in a vowel, remove the `s` at the end
- Words ending in `ões`, `ães` and `ãos` should end with `ão`
- Words ending in `is`, remove the `is` and add `l` to the end
  **Special case:** accents should be removed, if needed. The only cases I saw were `anéis` and `pastéis`, which have to be `anel` and `papel`.
- Words ending in `ns` get it replaced with `m`
- Words ending with `[rsz]es` should lose the `es`
  **Special case:** words ending in `eses` need the first `e` replaced with `ê`, like in `meses => mês`
- Some words are **always** used in the plural, like `óculos`, `parabéns` and `férias`.

Below, here's the code:

```
function plural_to_singular($string)
{
    if(preg_match('/^(?:[oó]culos|parab[eé]ns|f[eé]rias)$/iu', $string))
    {
        return $string;
    }

    $regexes = array(
        '[õã]es' => 'ão',
        '[áó].*eis' => 'el',
        '[eé]is' => 'el',
        '([^eé])is' => '$1l',
        'ns' => 'm',
        'eses' => 'ês',
        '([rzs])es' => '$1',
        's' => ''
    );

    foreach($regexes as $fragment => $replace)
    {
        $regex = '/' . $fragment . '$/ui';
        if(preg_match($regex, $string))
        {
            return preg_replace($regex, $replace, $string);
        }
    }

    return $string;
}
```

You can try it on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7947a0efd16f361e89491e4a64f71b578d2278df with some testcases

---

In your opinion, what can I improve?

Is there any obvious butchering or performance killer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than for simplicity of being able apply all replacement rules easily, and with more maintainable code, I don't see an absolute need to use regex for this, as simple string manipulation should be able to be used here and may be better from a performance standpoint.

There is no reason for you to loop over the regex array and `preg_replace()` each individually, as `preg_replace()` accepts arrays for both patterns and replacements.

So you could easily do something like:

```
preg_replace($pattern_array, $replacement_array, $string);
```

I don't like your approach of building the regex pattern in two places, why not define entire pattern in regex array?  You might have something like this:

```
$regex_config = array(
     'ão' => '/[õã]es$/iu',
    ...
);
$pattern_array = array_values($regex_config);
$replacement_array = array_keys($regex_config);
$result = preg_replace($pattern_array, $replacement_array, $string, 1);
```

You also have a potential edge case you might need to address.  What if subject string is all caps?  Since you use case-insenstive match you could end up with an all-caps plural word geting lowercase letters replaced into it.  Should you really be case-insensitive here?

Should your function name indicate that the function is only applicable to Portugeuse?

Comment: Won't your suggestion break for `meses`, which would return `mê` (since the `s` at the end is removed, as the last case, and is a required step)?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I didn't really speak to any specific pattern replacement logic, so I guess I don't understand your question.

Comment: In other words, if I write the code the way you suggest, would it still work for words that end with `s`, but that are singular?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I see your meaning now. I updated my answer to use limit parameter for the replacement. A limit value of 1 will limit the number of replacements that occur to 1, meaning cases where the a second replacement would have been triggered based on an earlier replacement will not happen.

Comment: Oh, yeah, the magical parameter that I always forget about! That's a great idea!

Answer (score 3):

Let me start by saying, that I have respect for Mike Brant, and have been enjoying his posts for quite a while now.  However, I disagree with some of his review.

1. `$regex_config` can not store the the replacement values as associative keys unless the regex patterns that use the same replacement value are merged.  This is not explained in the `...` (yatta-yatta).  The key clash would be on `el`.
2. Simply throwing `1` at the end of `preg_replace()` is NOT going to provide the desired output.  [Declaring a replacement limit on the call will only limit the replacements PER array element.](https://3v4l.org/EWnRp) The damage is evident in this output: [meses => mês = mê](https://3v4l.org/J9cl7)
3. Most trivially, `array_values()` doesn't need to be called because `preg_replace()` is "key ignorant" regarding the array inputs.

---

1. For this process to maintain accuracy, there needs to be a `return` as soon as a replacement occurs on the input string.  To avoid calling multiple replacements, iterate the array of pattern-replacement pairs.
2. You can avoid using capture groups and shorten your replacement strings in a couple places by implementing the `\K` metacharacter (restart fullstring match).  This way you don't need to use `$1` or rewrite a literals from the pattern into the replacement.
3. If you need to add case-sensitivity to your replacement process, you can check the last character of the incoming string.  If it is uppercase, assume the whole string is in CAPS and call `mb_strtoupper()`.
4. I don't have a sample string to test against `~[áó].*eis$~iu`, but I wonder if this is accurate/correct and my Portuguese is not too sharp.
5. After my implementation of `\K` you can see that two pairs of patterns are making the same replacement.  If you don't expect to be making lots of future adjustments to this set of regex patterns, you could combine the patterns with a pipe.  Here's what I mean: `'~(?:[áó].*eis|[eé]is)$~iu' => 'el',` and `'~(?:[rzs]\Kes|s)$~iu' => ''`
6. I am using the regex patterns as the keys because they will all logically be unique.  the same cannot be said about the replacement values (not without merging anyhow).

---

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vpHGS))

```
function is_allcaps($string)
{
    $last_letter = mb_substr($string, -1, 1, 'UTF-8');
    return $last_letter === mb_strtoupper($last_letter, 'UTF-8');
    // otherwise use cytpe_upper() and setlocale()
}

function plural_to_singular($string)
{
    // quick return of "untouchables"
    if(preg_match('~^(?:[oó]culos|parab[eé]ns|f[eé]rias)$~iu', $string))
    {
        return $string;
    }

    $regex_map = [
        '~[õã]es$~iu' => 'ão',
        '~(?:[áó].*e|[eé])is$~iu' => 'el',
        '~[^eé]\Kis$~iu' => 'l',
        '~ns$~iu' => 'm',
        '~eses$~iu' => 'ês',
        '~(?:[rzs]\Ke)?s$~iu' => ''
    ];

    foreach ($regex_map as $pattern => $replacement)
    {
        $singular = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string, 1, $count);
        if ($count)
        {
            return is_allcaps($string) ? mb_strtoupper($singular) : $singular;

        }
    }
    return $string;
}

$words = array(
    'óculos' => 'óculos',
    'papéis' => 'papel',
    'anéis' => 'anel',
    'PASTEIS' => 'PASTEL',
    'CAMIÕES' => 'CAMIÃO',
    'rodas' => 'roda',
    'cães' => 'cão',
    'meses' => 'mês',
    'vezes' => 'vez',
    'luzes' => 'luz',
    'cristais' => 'cristal',
    'canções' => 'canção',
    'nuvens' => 'nuvem',
    'alemães' => 'alemão'
);

foreach($words as $plural => $singular)
{
    echo "$plural => $singular = " , plural_to_singular($plural) , "\n";
}
```

Comment: @MikeBrant ping

Comment: @Toby do you feel that there maybe instances where a review/answer gives incorrect advice and is still upvote worthy?

Comment: Interesting question (probably this is the wrong place for such discussion - it sounds like something for [meta]).  On the whole, when I see an answer that has *bad* advice, I'll just comment, and only upvote when/if it's fixed.  OTOH, if an answer misses the most important point, but still makes at least one useful observation, it deserves an upvote.  But don't just ask me; ask [meta]!

Comment: I don't want to rollback your edit, because I understand your intent.  However, with my leading statement gone, my first bullets points are disconnected/nonsensical because they doesn't apply to the question.  I don't want to remove the review of Mike's post, because it has the green tick and will mislead researchers.

Comment: Ah, tricky.  Can we start with a neutral statement such as "I disagree with Mike's answer in these respects"?  Or just rollback - it's your answer, and if I didn't improve it, then you get the last say.  :-)

Comment: I really like your answer. I dislike the `mb_strtoupper`. the `[áó].*eis` is accurate, as there are words, ending in "eis" that have accents, like, "amáveis" and "amoláveis". You can use https://www.palavras.net/search.php?f=eis to search for more words (it is for pt-BR, but, it is fine). Those words should be replaced with "amável" and "maleável", which shows a bug in my code. That means the regex could be `([áó].*)eis` and replace with `$1el`. For the `[eé]is`, you have "anéis > anel" and for `([^eé])is` there's "barris > barril". This is just to showcase the differences [...]

Comment: [...] in those replacements, and why it is necessary for them to be different. Bundling them into a single regex is a good solution. One thing i strongly dislike, in your code, is the repetition of `~ ... ~iu`. Other than that, your code is fine and I like it. One thing I would do, that I didn't do before, it making `$regex_map` a static variable.

Comment: Great feedback, I shall update my answer.  So this is Portuguese from Portugal then? And how to handle `amoláveis`? Is it a one-off literal/static translation or is a regex pattern useful in targeting it and other words that require similar treatment?  Interim update with your feedback.  https://3v4l.org/oW8r8  p.s. my first choice was to use `set_locale()` and `ctype_upper()`, but it wasn't getting any joy in the demo, so I fellback to `mb_` calls.

Comment: Yes, it is Portuguese from Prtugal. And, to answer your other question, "amoláveis" should be "amolável". An example of a word with "ó" is "(i)móveis > (i)móvel" ("móvel" and "imóvel" are 2 words with 2-3 different meanings each). This caught me another bug: "fusíveis" should be "fusível". `s it a one-off literal/static translation or is a regex pattern useful in targeting it and other words that require similar treatment?` <-- I don't understand the question. If you're refering to making `$regex_map` a static variable, what I meant is `static $regex_map = [ ... ];`. [...]

Comment: [...] considering that this code is for PHP 5.3, you should use `array( ... )` instead of `[ ... ]`, as that syntax is for PHP 5.4+. I know PHP 5.3 is dead, but well... When I said that I "disliked that `mb_strtoupper`", I meant to say that I dislike to force everything to uppercase. One could use [`ucfirst()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) instead.

Comment: I didn't see any mention of PHP5.3 so I didn't design my snippet for a deprecated version.  That is a simple adjustment anyhow.  The logic that I am leveraging is not afforded by calling `ucfirst()`.  I am "checking" if the last letter of the input string is uppercase -- if yes, then it is assumed that the text is ALLCAPS; if not, then regardless of the first character's case, the replacement text should remain lowercase.  This should maintain accuracy because none of the replacement strings replace the 1st character of a word.